# How to perform Exact and partial match in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is the json:

```
{
"took": 3,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 5,
"successful": 5,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 2,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
{
"_index": "testing",
"_type": "skills",
"_id": "AV9FMnRfkEZ90S4dhzF6",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"skill": "java"
}
}
,
{
"_index": "testing",
"_type": "skills",
"_id": "AV9FM777kEZ90S4dhzF7",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"skill": "c language"
}
}
]
}
}
```

I have two dcuments and i need to get the partial and exact matching skills.

partial match:

Suppose if i give "c" then i should get the result "c language" skill.

Input:
c -> c language

Exact match:

Suppose if i give "java" then i should get the result "java" skill.

Input:
java -> java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Define your mapping by:

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "skill": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "analyzed",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CURL equivalent for above command:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "skill": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "analyzed",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Add documents:

```
POST index/type
{
  "skill":"c language"
}

POST index/type
{
  "skill":"java"
}
```

CURL equivalent for above commands:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index/type -d '
{
  "skill":"c language"
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index/type -d '
{
  "skill":"java"
}'
```

Search your documents:

Partial match:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "skill": "c"
    }
  }
}
```

Exact match:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "skill.keyword": "java"
    }
  }
}
```

CURL equivalent for above commands:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "skill": "c"
    }
  }
}'


curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "skill.keyword": "java"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is not working for you?

Comment: I have update my answer for ES 1.7 version. Check if this works for you.

Comment: When am searching for "C" am getting "java" results now

Comment: I downgraded to 1.7.2 and this is working perfectly for me. Revisit the steps and try again.

Comment: thank u so much...I need one more help...when am giving skill "c++" am not getting any result. This is the o/p am getting : {
"took": 1,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 5,
"successful": 5,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 0,
"max_score": null,
"hits": [ ]
}
}